# VScode How to stage only your selective changes and ignore other changes

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, salesforce

I'm wondering if it's possible to only stage/commit the added parts (green) to the file and ignore the deleted parts (red)?
Basically I don't want to override the file with the deleted parts and I just want to add the added parts .

[image: vs code]

Thanks!

**Problem:**
Basically I don't want to override the file with the deleted parts and I just want to add the added parts

This is what I see (for unstaged file):
[image]

**Solution:**
1- Opening up settings (On window/linux File > Preferences > Setting. On macOS Code > Preferences > Settings)
2- Search for diff
3- The specific setting is Diff Editor:Render Side by Side. Mark the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un-stage the file so in sidebar it moves to "Changed" category. Click it on the sidebar.

You should see old & new side by side. If there are changes you don't want to commit (they aren't your edits, maybe they should belong in another branch etc) you should see arrows to undo the change, put the old block back.

Click the arrow next to the red blocks (or copy paste them from left to right but that's more work). Save the file. (I hope you don't have autodeployment on save). Stage the file again and it should contain only the changes you consciously let in.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have the file unstaged now but not sure to see the side by side view that you have in your screenshot. I will add screenshot of what I see for unstaged in the question. thanks.

Comment: I found out how to get the side by side view and then I was able to follow your instructions: 
1- Opening up settings (On window/linux File > Preferences > Setting. On macOS Code > Preferences > Settings)
2- Search for diff
3- The specific setting is Diff Editor:Render Side by Side. Mark the checkbox.